# Appending nil to a dependently typed length indexed vector in Lean

Tags: proof, dependent-type, lean

Assume the following definition:

```
def app {α : Type} : Π{m n : ℕ}, vector α m → vector α n → vector α (n + m)
    | 0 _ [] v                   := by simp [add_zero]; assumption
    | (nat.succ _) _ (h :: t) v' := begin apply vector.cons,
                                              exact h,
                                          apply app t v'
                                    end
```

Do note that `(n + m)` are flipped in the definition, so as to avoid plugging `add_symm` into the definition. Also, remember that `add / +` is defined on rhs in Lean. `vector` is a hand rolled nil / cons defined length indexed list.

So anyway, first we have a lemma that follows from definition:

```
theorem nil_app_v {α : Type} : ∀{n : ℕ} (v : vector α n),
    v = [] ++ v := assume n v, rfl
```

Now we have a lemma that doesn't follow from definition, as such I use `eq.rec` to formulate it.

```
theorem app_nil_v {α : Type} : ∀{n : ℕ} (v : vector α n),
    v = eq.rec (v ++ []) (zero_add n)
```

Note that `eq.rec` is just `C y → Π {a : X}, y = a → C a`.

The idea of a proof is trivial by induction on `v`. The base case follows immediately from definition, the recursive case should follow immediately from the inductive hypothesis and definition, but I can't convince Lean of this.

```
begin
  intros n v,
  induction v,
    -- base case
    refl,
    -- inductive case
end
```

The inductive hypothesis I get from Lean is `a_1 = eq.rec (a_1 ++ vector.nil) (zero_add n_1)`.

How do I use it with conclusion `a :: a_1 = eq.rec (a :: a_1 ++ vector.nil) (zero_add (nat.succ n_1))`? I can `unfold app` to reduce the term `a :: a_1 ++ vector.nil` to `a :: (a_1 ++ vector.nil)`, and now I am stuck.

Comment: If you have axiom K, you can prove an auxiliary lemma saying that `eq.rec _ eq1 (x :: xs) = x :: eq.rec _ eq2 xs` no matter what `eq1` and `eq2` are.

Comment: @gallais Does assertion of streicher's K influence code generation? Am I still constructive (on decidable domains)?

Comment: @gallais So I did a bit more reading, turns out this ends up being equivalent with heterogenous equality, which would then make sense.